# View all availble table/dataset inside a zipped package

Tags: r

I  am new to world of R.I have loaded a dataset using following command

```
install.packages("gcookbook")
library(gcookbook)
```

gcookbook have few datasets.what is the command in R to see all those data sets inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all datasets in a package by running `data(package = "gcookbook")` or simply `data()` if you want to see all currently available datasets ordered by package. You can read more about this command if you type `?data`